# How expensive is a bash function call really?

Tags: bash

Just out if interest, are there any sources on how expensive function calls in Bash really are? I expect them to be several times slower than executing the code within them directly but I can't seem to find anything about this.

Comment: Curiosity is fine. But don't get on a wrong track here. Most of the tasks you do in a shell (shell scripts) is either I/O bound or involves starting external processes, handling their I/O etc. So any overhead that comes from custom (ba)sh functions should be irrelevant. If you're doing something else in bash, where that actually matters, consider using a different tool for the task.

Comment: given that bash is a relatively slow interpreter, I wouldn't expect that there would be much practical difference as the interpretation and execution of the statements themselves likely dominates the time cost.

Comment: 1) if you worry about performance, you picked the wrong language. 2) why don't you test it?

Comment: Rule 1 of Optimization Club: Do not optimize.  Rule 2 of Optimization Club: Do not optimize without measuring.  http://xoa.petdance.com/Rules_of_Optimization_Club

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41315367/717267

Comment: [Archive Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141215045528/http://xoa.petdance.com/Rules_of_Optimization_Club) to the Rules of Optimization Club

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't really agree that performance should not be a worry when programming in bash. It's actually a very good question to ask.

Here's a possible benchmark, comparing the builtin `true` and the command `true`, the full path of which is `/bin/true` on my machine.

On my machine:

```
$ time for i in {0..1000}; do true; done

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time for i in {0..1000}; do /bin/true; done

real    0m2.660s
user    0m2.880s
sys 0m2.344s
```

Amazing! That's about 2 to 3 ms wasted by just forking a process (on my machine)!

So next time you have some large text file to process, you'll avoid the mistaken long chains of piped `cat`s, `grep`s, `awk`s, `cut`s, `tr`s, `sed`s, `head`s, `tail`s, `you-name-it`s. Besides, UNIX pipes and also very slow (will that be your next question?).

Imagine you have a 1000 line file, and in each line you put one `cat` then a `grep` then a `sed` and then an `awk` (no, don't laugh, you can see even worse by going through the posts on this site!), then you're already wasting (on my machine) at least 2*4*1000=8000ms=8s just forking stupid and useless processes.

To answer your comment about pipes...

###Subshells

Subshells are very slow:

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do (true); done

real    0m2.465s
user    0m2.812s
sys 0m2.140s
```

Amazing! over 2ms per subshell (on my machine).

###Pipes

Pipes are also very slow (this should be obvious regarding the fact that they involve subshells):

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do true | true; done

real    0m4.769s
user    0m5.652s
sys 0m4.240s
```

Amazing! over 4ms per pipe (on my machine), so that's 2ms for just the pipe after subtracting the time for the subshell.

#### Redirection

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do true > file; done

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.008s
```

So that's pretty fast.

Ok, you probably also want to see it in action with creation of a file:

```
$ rm file*; time for i in {1..1000}; do true > file$i; done

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Still decently fast.

#### Pipes vs redirections:

In your comment, you mention:

```
sed '' filein > filetmp; sed '' filetmp > fileout
```

vs

```
sed '' filein | sed '' > fileout
```

(Of course, the best thing would be to use a single instance of `sed` (it's usually possible), but that doesn't answer the question.)

Let's check that out:

A funny way:

```
$ rm file*
$ > file
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do sed '' file | sed '' > file$i; done

real    0m5.842s
user    0m4.752s
sys 0m5.388s
$ rm file*
$ > file
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do sed '' file > filetmp$i; sed '' filetmp$i > file$i; done

real    0m6.723s
user    0m4.812s
sys 0m5.800s
```

So it seems faster to use a pipe rather than using a temporary file (for sed). In fact, this could have been understood without typing the lines: in a pipe, as soon as the first `sed` spits out something, the second `sed` starts processing the data. In the second case, the first `sed` does its job, and then the second `sed` does its job.

So our experiment is not a good way of determining if pipes are better that redirections.

How about process substitutions?

```
$ rm file*
$ > file
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do sed '' > file$i < <(sed '' file); done

real    0m7.899s
user    0m1.572s
sys 0m3.712s
```

Wow, that's slow! Hey, but observe the user and system CPU usage: much less than the other two possibilities (if someone can explain that...)

Comment: Can you post an amendment showing how pipes are "very slow"? My experience is that When compared to serial processing of /tmp/outputfiles, i.e. (for example `sed file1 > file2; sed file2 > file3; .... ` VS `sed file1 | sed file2 | sed file3`), they greatly improve the overall runtime of script.

Comment: @shellter Updated the post a little bit. Hopefully, I also explained why `sed '' in | sed ''` is faster than `sed '' in > tmp; sed '' tmp`.

Comment: Though it doesn't answer my question (I asked about the cost of functions, not forking a new process) I accept this answer as it is really detailed and high quality (I actually learned quite a few things).