# Bash Script is super slow

Tags: performance, bash

I'm updating an old script to parse ARP data and get useful information out of it.  We added a new router and while I can pull the ARP data out of the router it's in a new format. I've got a file "zTempMonth" which is a all the arp data from both sets of routers that I need to compile down into a new data format that's normalized.  The below lines of code do what I need them to logically - but it's extremely slow - as in it will take days to run these loops where previously the script took 20-30 minutes.  Is there a way to speed this up, or identify what's slowing it down?

Thank you in advance,

```
    echo "Parsing zTempMonth"
    while read LINE
    do
            wc=`echo $LINE | wc -w`
            if [[ $wc -eq "6" ]]; then
                    true
                    out=$(echo $LINE | awk '{ print $2 " " $4 " " $6}')
                    echo $out >> zTempMonth.tmp

            else
                    false
            fi

            if [[ $wc -eq "4" ]]; then
                    true
                    out=$(echo $LINE | awk '{ print $1 " " $3 " " $4}')
                    echo $out >> zTempMonth.tmp
            else
                    false
            fi


    done < zTempMonth
```

Comment: It's probably a mistake to do any kind of sophisticated text processing using a while read loop. You might consider rewriting this in awk or even a general purpose programming language.

Comment: Too many forks to (useless) external commands. Lots of (useless) opening and closing files. Besides, a while loop to read a file line by line is notoriously slow in Bash. Not mentioning that your style is terrible (quotes missing); I hope you're not using this in prod.

Comment: What are those `true` and `false` barewords doing there, btw? I realize if they're the last thing the script sees they will reflect in `$?`, but that's a pretty arcane way to yield success/failure.

Comment: The true and false were there so I could comment out lines  while troubleshooting without causing statement blocks issues.

Comment: What was the previous script that ran so much faster? Is the new router adding *huge* amounts of data?

Comment: @EtanReisner It's not more data, just stored in a different format.  This is an insert to the previous script to normalize the data for later processing.

Comment: If the data format is all that changed then I question the assertion that the old script could run in as little as 20-30 minutes if the current one runs in days. The change in the script for the extra tests is expensive but I don't believe it is *that* expensive unless the number of lines changed drastically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. While read loops are slow.
2. Subshells in a loop are slow.
3. `>>` (`open(f, 'a')`) calls in a loop are slow.

You could speed this up and remain in pure bash, just by losing #2 and #3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -a line; do
    case "${#line[@]}" in
        6) printf '%s %s %s\n' "${line[1]}" "${line[3]}" "${line[5]}";;
        4) printf '%s %s %s\n' "${line[0]}" "${line[2]}" "${line[3]}";;
    esac
done < zTempMonth >> zTempMonth.tmp
```

But if there are more than a few lines, this will still be slower than pure awk. Consider an awk script as simple as this:

```
BEGIN {
    print "Parsing zTempMonth"
}   

NF == 6 {
    print $2 " " $4 " " $6
}   

NF == 4 {
    print $1 " " $3 " " $4
}
```

You could execute it like this:

```
awk -f thatAwkScript zTempMonth >> zTempMonth.tmp
```

to get the same append approach as your current script.

Answer (score 7):

When writing shell scripts, it’s almost always better to call a function directly rather than using a subshell to call the function. The usual convention that I’ve seen is to echo the return value of the function and capture that output using a subshell. For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function get_path() {
  echo "/path/to/something"
}

mypath="$(get_path)"
```

This works fine, but there is a significant speed overhead to using a subshell and there is a much faster alternative. Instead, you can just have a convention wherein a particular variable is always the return value of the function (I use retval). This has the added benefit of also allowing you to return arrays from your functions.

If you don’t know what a subshell is, for the purposes of this blog post, a subshell is another bash shell that is spawned whenever you use `$()` or ``` `` ``` and is used to execute the code you put inside.

I did some simple testing to allow you to observe the overhead. For two functionally equivalent scripts:

This one uses a subshell:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function a() {
  echo hello
}

for (( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )); do
  echo "$(a)"
done
```

This one uses a variable:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function a() {
  retval="hello"
}

for (( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )); do
  a
  echo "$retval"
done
```

The speed difference between these two is noticeable and significant.

```
$ for i in variable subshell; do
> echo -e "\n$i"; time ./$i > /dev/null
> done

variable

real 0m0.367s
user 0m0.346s
sys 0m0.015s

subshell

real 0m11.937s
user 0m3.121s
sys 0m0.359s
```

As you can see, when using `variable`, execution takes 0.367 seconds. subshell however takes a full 11.937 seconds!

Source: http://rus.har.mn/blog/2010-07-05/subshells/