# shell script subtract fields from pairs of lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Suppose I have the following file:

```
stub-foo-start: 10
stub-foo-stop: 15
stub-bar-start: 3
stub-bar-stop: 7
stub-car-start: 21
stub-car-stop: 51
# ... 
# EOF at the end
```

with the goal of writing a script which would append to it like so:

```
stub-foo-start: 10
stub-foo-stop: 15
stub-bar-start: 3
stub-bar-stop: 7
stub-car-start: 21
stub-car-stop: 51
# ...
# appended: 
stub-foo: 5        # 5 = stop(15) - start(10)
stub-bar: 4        # and so on... 
stub-car: 30
# ...
# new EOF
```

The format is exactly this sequential pairing of `start` and `stop` tags (stop being the closing one) and no nesting in between.

What is the recommended approach to writing such a script using `awk` and/or `sed`? Mostly, what I've tried is `grep`ing lines, storing to a variable, but that seemed to overcomplicate things and trail off.

Any advice or helpful links welcome. (Most tutorials I found on shell scripting were illustrative at best)

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Just my 1/50 of a currency unit: Writing this using bash or sh scripts is not easy as it is not really what these two programming languages were made for. I'd use Python or PHP, because they're quick for protyping and I'm fluent in their use, but I can also imagine e.g. Lua or ECMA-Script being similarly useful.

Comment: need more details, eg: what to do if there are more than 2x entries with the same matching string (eg, 4 lines that start with `stub-foo`)? is the input file already sorted by the first field? will the numbers (field #2) always be increasing (eg, what to do with `stub-foo-1: 12 / stub-foo-2: 5 / stub-foo-3: 23`)?  does the output require the comments to be included (eg, should ` // (15-10)` be in the final output)? do all field #1 strings start with `stub`? can field #1 have more than 2 hyphens (eg, is `stub-widget-color-green` possible)?  please update the question with the additional details

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I had similiar thoughts at first - 'awk' and 'sed' felt like weird tools for this particular problem, unreadable at the very best. This is also why I haven't posted any attempted code, it was gibberish piping, much like the one mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801795/how-expensive-is-a-bash-function-call-really 
Do you think python would be a suitable substitute for a shell script performance-wise ? (easier to code definitely)

Comment: @markp-fuso; thanks, I've updated the question with more clarity

Comment: Take a Python tutorial. It will take you a day or two, but then you have an idea of how the language looks, which is worth it. Same goes for the other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -F '[ -]' '{ map[$2][$3]=$4;print } END { for (i in map) { print i": "(map[i]["stop:"]-map[i]["start:"])" // ("map[i]["stop:"]"-"-map[i]["start:"]")" } }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F '[ -]' '{                                                       # Set the field delimiter to space or "-"
                 map[$2][$3]=$4;                                       # Create a two dimensional array with the second and third field as indexes and the fourth field as the value
                 print                                                 # Print the line
               } 
           END { for (i in map) { 
                 print i": "(map[i]["stop:"]-map[i]["start:"])" // ("map[i]["stop:"]"-"-map[i]["start:"]")"                                                      # Loop through the array and print the data in the required format
                 } 
                }' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the commentary, I probably would've asked for it otherwise

Answer (score 2):

A naive implementation in plain `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r start && read -r stop; do
    printf '%s: %d\n' "${start%-*}" $(( ${stop##*:} - ${start##*:} )) 
done < file
```

This assumes pairs are contiguous and there are no interlaced or nested pairs.

Comment: Normally, would've went for something like this, but I'll choose Raman's awk-only solution